# WinForm User Controls - Drag Drop

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

Is it just me... but I thought you could drag/drop User Controls onto WinForms? Can't drag them to the toolbar either. Maybe I'm having a VB6 flashback. It must be missing something simple I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do drag-drop from the solution explorer, no. When you build the solution the controls should be automatically added to the toolbox (in a separate group in the top), from which you can add them as you do with other controls.

Update: just for completeness for anyone who stumbles upon this answer; this is what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: hmmm. I don't see where my control gets added. weird. can't find it.

Comment: oh. wait. now I see it. I should be fired for asking such a simple question.

Comment: I promise I won't tell anyone ;)

Answer (score 1):

But not really... in fact.. controls on the toolbar are not sorted.. so that can be a catch..